# How Can I print users selected?

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem with JavaScript! I want to print users selected thing in Javascript!

For Example:

We have a list

Apple

Coffe

Banana

If users select banana I wanna return it like this "You selected banana"(Sorry my bad English)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's a place where we help you with your code; we don't write code for you. [Please see How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show us what you've tried, then we can help, and be sure to post all *relevant* code in the question.

Comment: Please, share what you already have done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `select` and add a change event listener.

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select'),
res = document.querySelector('p');
select.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  res.textContent = 'You selected '+this.value;
});
```

```html
<select>
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Coffe">Coffe</option>
<option value="Banana">Banana</option>
</select>
<p></p>
```